# When navigating through word-wrapped text in VIM, how to make the selector move onto wrapped line sections?

Tags: vim

The behaviour I want is the behaviour in most text editors and office applications (that aren't designed with programmers in mind). This makes it quicker to get to the centre of large paragraphs.

Thanks.

Comment: I wanted this from time to time.  Luckily, most of my editing in Vim has been with code and not human documents.  Nonetheless, I think this question is Vim-centric and not programming-centric, thus belongs on Superuser instead.

Comment: @strager: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not certain that I understand your question, but try the commands `gj` and `gk`, instead of `j` and `k`. I think they do what you want. I've put together a screencast with a few tips for [working with 'soft wrapped'](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/soft-wrapping-text/) text (which I guess is the same as 'word-wrapped' text).